# setArguments and getArguments return empty string

Tags: java, android

When I'm using bundle to send values to the fragment it always returns empty values

This is my dialog fragment

```java
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String Tag = "CustomDialog";
    private static final String DIALOG_MESSAGE_1 = "title_text";
    private static final String DIALOG_MESSAGE_2 = "message_text";
    private String title_text, message_text;

    public static CustomDialog newInstance(int num, String title_text, String message_text){
        CustomDialog dialogFragment = new CustomDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        args.putString(DIALOG_MESSAGE_1, title_text);
        args.putString(DIALOG_MESSAGE_2, message_text);
        Log.e("test", args.getString(DIALOG_MESSAGE_2));
        dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
        return dialogFragment;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            title_text = bundle.getString(DIALOG_MESSAGE_1);
            message_text = bundle.getString(DIALOG_MESSAGE_2);
        }

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())...create();
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling the dialog

```java
    private void doLogOut(){
        CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String title_text = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.logout_header);
        String message_text = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.logout_message);
        DialogFragment dialogFrag = CustomDialog.newInstance(1, title_text, message_text);
        dialogFrag.setTargetFragment(this, 1);
        dialogFrag.setArguments(bundle);
        dialogFrag.show(getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "dialog");
    }
```

But the values always are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `doLogOut` function you're resetting the arguments by passing an empty bundle, remove `dialogFrag.setArguments(bundle);` and I think it will work fine.